# Is language inherently circular?

Tags: meaning, etymology, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I looked up "Hallelujah" in [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chant&allowed_in_frame=0) today, and the result, as often happens with etymological research, ended in following a rabbit warren of possibilities.

Take the word "Hallelujah" for example.

This apparently springs from the Hebrew hallalu-yah (praise-Jehovah). Following up on "praise", the etymological roots are linked to the idea of "price" and "value". This is, of course, a dangerous, and ultimately deceptive route for researching etymological roots, as etymology is the study of (a) chronology and (B) geography (and the its linguistic implications).

So, I looked again at [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chant&allowed_in_frame=0), to find that "hillel" (he praised), was "of imitative origin, with primary sense being "to trill."."

So, "to praise" in its original Hebrew terms had its etymological roots in "to sing".

Now, I realise that to go beyond this chronologically would be futile (or very difficult to say the least), so I searched the etymological roots of "trill" and "sing" to see what conceptual links they brought about (I am aware, of course, that these concepts may not have been congruous with the Hebrew concept of "to sing", but I am hopeful that that they 
may shed light on the root (though this is, of course, conjectural)).

So, looking at the roots of "sing" brought up, other than circular links of variations of " to sing", was "sengwh- "to sing, make an incantation." ".

Now, to "incantation" clearly has its roots in magic.

My question, therefore, is ultimately metaphysical. Can one go beyond "magic" and "sing" to define a term that is , at best, instinctive, and at least culturally significant?

NB: I realise this question doesn't do justice to, or even qualify the use of the title, but the question clearly has larger implications that are communicable within a forum setting.

Comment: One needs a better dictionary than etymonline if you want to do this stuff. An etymology that says "of imitative origin" is saying nothing. First, Hebrew and English are unrelated, hence share no cognates. Second, singing, talking, praying, and praising are all linguistic events, and it's natural for their translations to echo one another like this. You can do it with any bilingual dictionary: pick a word and look up all its definitions in the other side; then look up all **their** definitions on the first side. You'd think two or three trials would lead to every word; but it usually converges

Comment: Convergence is really at the heart of this question, however badly put. etymonline incidentally has some excellent [sources](http://www.etymonline.com/sources.php?allowed_in_frame=0). These comments certainly agree with the OED. I have unfortunately been unable to purchase the HTOED, as I consider it a luxury!

Comment: "of imitative origin" certainly is ambiguous. Which sources would you suggest (aside from bilingual dictionaries)? Or are bilingual dictionaries the best way to study this in your opinion?

Comment: _The American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Roots_ is excellent, especially in conjunction with Buck's _Dictionary of Selected Synonyms in the Principal Indo-European Languages_. Both are available in paperback.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions. Perhaps it is slightly prejudicial, but I am a little concerned with American roots (I suppose being once removed from English roots)...?

Comment: @martin - may I ask you why you think American English is once removed from English roots? Are you aware that Latin roots don't change, as Middle English roots don't change, as Greek roots don't change, as French roots don't change, etc., just by crossing an ocean?

Comment: @medica: Martin's referring to the title of the "American Heritage Dictionary". It's just a title, and the major difference -- pronunciation -- is not dealt with very well in that dictionary, so it doesn't make any difference in the end. (If you want American English pronunciation, Kenyon and Knott is the gold standard; or use the English side of a <Language>-English bilingual dictionary -- they'll have the English pronunciations in IPA.) But the etymologies in the AHD of PIE Roots are quite reliable and go as far back as possible. Plus, there's an index of Semitic roots, too.

Comment: This methodology is flawed. Looking up a word in one language and expecting the words of the definition in the other to reflect back on the first in any way is flawed.  Hallelujah might be defined as praise, but nothing else is going to reflect meaning back on the English word praise and its own derivation.

Comment: An etymology that says "not of imitative origin" would be interesting. I remember reading somewhere that 'gas' is generally agreed to be a word just made up out of thin air by someone needing it. Perhaps the only one.

Comment: The root radical is הלל (HLL). 4000 years ago an LA teenager traveled back in time and wrote LOL in Phoenician, to teach the philistines humour. Soon, the Phoenician version mutated in Hebrew and Aramaic. And then they added the definite article (ה) - HaLOL. But as you are aware, Hebrew and Aramaic do not encode vowels in their root radicals. So, it became HLL. And then the Arabs caught on, and thought eating kosher should be fun and therefore - halal.

Comment: OED: **Hallel** f. Heb. *hallēl*, inf. and imper. ‘praise, celebrate’, a vb. in the Piel conjugation, with which Ps. cxiii begins — whence **hallelujah** Heb. *hallĕlū-yāh* ‘praise (ye) Jah (= Jehovah)’; the verb is the imper. plural of *hallēl*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it says that it is about metaphysics, not about English.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about languages in general and not the English language in particular.

Comment: As all words are manifestations of the creative logos, they are, by definition, conduits which manifest meaning - I wouldn't call their function circular, though.

Comment: This is definitely better suited to the linguistics stackexchange.

Comment: yes, language is almost always inherently circularly defined unless externally defined. this is actually somewhat apparent if you closely consider godel's incompleteness theorem